# How to search keywords and get matching words with Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search for for some keywods in mytext field and get matching keywords with this same query. Is there any way to query this?

I can search for keywords with different ways but I can't get matching results.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mytext REGEXP 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3';
```

Here is an example query result;

```
 +---------+---------------------------+-----------------+
 |      id | mytext                    |matchingWords    |
 +---------+---------------------------+-----------------+
 |     101 | keyword1aabbkeyword2      |keyword1,keyword2|
 |     102 | keyword2adfsadfadsfa      |keyword2         |
 |     103 | adfdsfa                   |                 |
 |     104 | assfb                     |                 |
 +---------+---------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean with `get matching keywords with this same query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a concatenation of matching keywords. I'd use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this:

```
select 
  id, 
  mytext,
  (
    select group_concat(word)
    from
    (
      select 'keyword1' as word
      union all 
      select 'keyword2' as word
      union all 
      select 'keyword3' as word
    ) w
    where t.mytext like concat('%', w.word, '%')
  ) as matching_words
from mytable t;
```

With this query it's easy to change the words you are looking up. You can even use a separate table for them, so your query does not have to create one on-the-fly and thus does not have to get modified at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
  IF (mytext REGEXP 'keyword1', 1, 0) matchingKeyword1,
  IF (mytext REGEXP 'keyword2', 1, 0) matchingKeyword2,
  IF (mytext REGEXP 'keyword3', 1, 0) matchingKeyword3
FROM table WHERE mytext REGEXP 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 select ID, mytext, concat_ws(   IF (mytext REGEXP
 'keyword1','keyword1' , '') ,   IF (mytext REGEXP 'keyword2',
 'keyword2', '') ) FROM table WHERE mytext REGEXP
 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' FROM table ;
```